# Factory reset Samsung Galaxy S3 without screen

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, factory-reset, broken-screen

The screen on my Samsung Galaxy S3 has bitten the dust, and is now remains completely black. The phone otherwise seems to be working, however (sounds play, the notification lights light, the touch screen seems to respond, etc.)

I think I'll give it away to anyone who wants it for parts. But first I want to wipe my data off it. Unfortunately, since I can't see the screen, instructions such as "Scroll down to 'Factory reset'" won't work.

Can anyone tell me the exact sequence of button presses to do a factory reset from the bootloader, without seeing the screen?

(Unfortunately, the phone isn't set up with Android Device Manager.)

Comment: You should be able to wipe from recovery mode. Just search Google for a few screenshots and you know how to do it. And you haven't got any warranty more?

Comment: Or You can use ADB

Comment: @Ash-Ishh..: I think I need to allow or set up a debug connection on the phone before I can use ADB, don't I?

Comment: @SuperThomasLab: Yes, that's what I want to do, but since I can't see what I'm doing at all, I haven't had any success. I could use some more information on timing, when the phone vibrates, the order of the yes/no prompt, and that sort of thing.

Comment: @kundor ADB is default enabled in Recovery (at least in custom ones, don't know about your stock Recovery). You just need to somehow boot into Recovery using key combinations and then take care of rest using ADB. Can you boot into fastboot mode? You can erase/flash userdata using fastboot commands. I don't know about Samsung but I guess some tools that I hear most of the time like Odin, Heimdall and similar ones may help here. Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use recovery mode and guess the controls from resources available online or you could use adb if u had developer options enabled and type:

```
adb shell
--wipe_data
```

**EDIT:** I read the comments on your question and it looks like if u wanted to reset it you can go into recovery (Home+VolumeUp+Power) and then press volume down twice and then press power and then press volume down 6 times and then press power again.

Comment: Well, I've tried the button presses at least a dozen times with no success. When I turn it on with Home+Volume Up+Power, it buzzes, then a couple of seconds after I let go of the buttons, it buzzes again. Does it matter if I press volume down before or after this second buzz? Is there a delay before the second menu loads (when I press volume down six times)? Does the indicator LED light up at any point?

Comment: Keep the VolUp+Home+Power button combination held for 7 seconds then release Power and keep holding VolUp+Home for another 7 seconds then perform the VolDown twice then Power then VolDown six times then Power button presses.

Comment: No Problem, glad I could be of assistance! :D

Answer (score 1):

This link shows the exact clicks for factory reset without a screen:
http://visihow.com/Is_there_a_way_to_reset_a_Samsung_Galaxy_Note_3_without_the_screen

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Otherwise, your answer becomes useless in case the link dies. For further hints, please see: [How do I write a good answer](http://android.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).